Can I merge or compose graphs in langgraph
We have separately implemented two separate graphs but want to be able to use one as a subgraph of the other.
Can it be done in langgraph?
Edit: https://langchain-ai.github.io/langgraph/how-tos/subgraph/#create-parent-child-graphs appears to be what I am looking for.

Have you already checked this : https://langchain-ai.github.io/langgraph/how-tos/subgraph/
What have you tried and haven't tried so far?

I wasn't aware of subgraphs in langgraph, hence the question. Thanks for the info.
